# Loading properties file not in my classpath through spring

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to load properties file through Spring which is not in my classpath? I tried something like this

```
<bean id="variableProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:network.properties</value>
        <value>/conf/app.properties</value>
    </list>
    </property>
```

Here /conf/app.properties is not loaded and throwing

```
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath resource [conf/app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: Update the question showing the directory structure of your deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `file:/conf/app.properties` but I think you have to put absolute path in it

Comment: The above solution worked. Thank you!